# Displaying TIFF data on React-Leaflet Map

Tags: leaflet, mapping, gis, react-leaflet, geotiff

I have basic javascript code that uses a simple Leaflet map; I have TIFF files that I parse through, and then I can display these on the map though Layer Control, in a simple index.html file. I can't figure out how to show the TIFF data in react-leaflet though. I can parse the data properly, but react-leaflet only seems to take PNG or PNG url's, and I can't find any documentation or anything that shows how to show TIFF files. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but it's super frustrating :(

This is my code with react, and react-leaflet. It's working + parsing the TIFF data, I just don't know how to add the data to the layerscontrol baselayer TileLayer...

```
import React, { useMemo, useState } from "react";
import {
    TileLayer, 
    Marker, 
    Popup, 
    MapContainer, 
    LayersControl, 
    LayerGroup, 
    FeatureGroup, 
    Circle,
    useMap,
    } from 'react-leaflet';
import chroma from 'chroma-js';
import parseGeoraster from 'georaster';
import GeoRasterLayer from 'georaster-layer-for-leaflet';
import AddLocate from "../components/AddLocate";
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import sample from '../data/tmin.tiff';

const MapBody = () => {
  const center = [0, 0];
  let tmin_layer = '';
  
  fetch(sample)
  .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
  .then(arrayBuffer => {
      parseGeoraster(arrayBuffer).then(georaster => {
        const min = georaster.mins[0];
        const max = georaster.maxs[0];
        const range = georaster.ranges[0];
        const scale = chroma.scale('Spectral').domain([1, 0]);
          tmin_layer = new GeoRasterLayer({
          georaster: georaster,
          opacity: 0.7,
          pixelValuesToColorFn: function (pixelValues) {
              var pixelValue = pixelValues[0]; 
              if (pixelValue === 0) return null;
              const scaledPixelValue = (pixelValue - min) / range;
              const color = scale(scaledPixelValue).hex();
              return color;
          },
          resolution: 256
      });
      console.log("layer:", tmin_layer);
    })
  })
  

  return (
    <>
    <Helmet>
      <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
      />
    </Helmet>
    <MapContainer className="map" center={center} zoom={2} scrollWheelZoom={false} doubleClickZoom={true}>
        <TileLayer
        className="tile"
        attribution='&amp;copy <a href="https://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        //prevents map duplicating
        noWrap={true} />   

      <LayersControl position="topright">  
      <LayersControl.BaseLayer name="TOPO TESTING">
          <TileLayer className="tiles" url="https://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"/>
      </LayersControl.BaseLayer>

      <LayersControl.BaseLayer name="TIFF TEST">
        <TileLayer className="tiffy" url={tmin_layer}/>    
      </LayersControl.BaseLayer>

      </LayersControl> 
      <AddLocate/>
    </MapContainer>
  </>
  )
} 
export default MapBody;
```

Comment: nvm i figured it out

Comment: Can u post your answer?

Comment: How did you solve it @andyspears ? I'd appreciate an answer